# How to choose right shard key for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

My document structure is:

```
"_id": ObjectId("50c41fae0e708237dc7a5187"),
"uid": "999",
"appname": "authentication",
"activityId": "login",
"activityName": "login",
"date": ISODate("2012-12-09T05: 20: 46.117Z"),
"yearmonth": "201212"
```

uid is userid generated by other application from RDMS sequences.
yearmonth is artificial field I have created in the apps only for the purpose of better shard key.

Write pattern:
As user login or perform specific action on a site, I write event into mongoDB. This means uid is relatively random with very high cardinality. 
For the same uid I can write hundreds of events.

Read pattern:
Most queries are based on uid as a first query parameter. {uid:"9999",date:{$gt: ....}, activityId:'login'}

My initial shard key was  {uid:1, date:1}. -  to provide a good query isolation and have splittable chunks if any one uid has too many documents. 
Now, based on [How to choose a shard key](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/01/04/how-to-choose-a-shard-key-the-card-game/): the card game article and some webinar and comments on this forum I realize that better key should be something with
{coarse timestamp:1 , search criteria:1} . Idea is to have better locality for the shard key to help with write performance.
so I have created yearmonth field and thinking about changing my shard key to {yearmonth:1, uid:1}

The question is:
Do I loose query isolation and performance of read operation because of the change?
My query parameter will not match first element of the shard key anymore.

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798590/finding-a-good-index-and-shard-key-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I would just stick with uid as that is the key you are going to use to fetch the data.

**Shard key** - uid

Especially when it is a random uid based event insert and read, it would be very optimal to keep the uid as the shard key.

When the chunks grow bigger, the **Balancer in the MongoDB** is going to automatically balance the chunks across different shard servers.  So you are covered here as well (as the automatic balance will take care of some shard server growing too bigger).

Hope this helps.